# How to store cart using Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::save() in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

Here is my controller code i try to save but it gives save method not define on Cart.

I also try with "Cart::add()" method but result are the same. I search this on many sites but dont get any good ans. kindly help me.

```
$cart = new Cart;
$cart->user_id = Auth::id();
$cart->product_id = $request->input('product_id');
$cart->product_variant_id = $request->input('product_variant_id');
$cart->quantity = $request->input('quantity');
$cart->save();
```

Comment: if the error is `save method not define on Cart`, please check if this method is defined in your Cart class

Comment: i search then i find to use add method for save data into cart i try add() but doesn't work for me

Comment: That package does NOT have a save method. Add adds items to the shopping cart. If it isn't working for you, maybe you're using it wrong?

Comment: I use add() like this
Cart::add(['id' => '293ad', 'name' => 'Product1', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 9.99]);

Answer (score 0):

The `save()` method on `Cart` class doesn't exist, use add as it says on documentation: https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart

```
//Parameters (id, name, quantity, price)
Cart::add('293ad', 'Product 1', 1, 9.99);
```

Or it can also receive an array of products:

```
Cart::add([
  ['id' => '293ad', 'name' => 'Product 1', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 10.00],
  ['id' => '4832k', 'name' => 'Product 2', 'qty' => 1, 'price' => 10.00, 'options' => ['size' => 'large']]
]);
```

If neither of these work, please verify that you have installed it correctly, make sure you have added the provider inside providers array in `config/app.php` file:

```
Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\ShoppingcartServiceProvider::class
```

Also make sure the alias of the class is there inside aliases array:

```
'Cart' => Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\Facades\Cart::class,
```

After this, I would recommend running command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

And for Laravel 5.4 or below also:

```
composer dump-autoload
```